# Movie Clip Object adding Multiple Times with Enter_Frame Event

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, gsap, enterframeevent

Hey Guys so I am using TweenLite to act as a timer for Performance with Mobile usage. I ran into a little problem here that I can't seem to figure out. So In my ENTER_FRAME Listener I have this function `difficultyController` Where I add my TweenLite control like so:

```
    private function difficultyController():void 
    {
        if (nScore >= 10)
        {
            TweenLite.delayedCall(nChainsaw, addChainsaw);
            trace("DIFFICULTY_UPDATE");
        }
    }
```

In my `addChainsaw` Function I have the Movie Clip Objects added to the stage like so:

```
    private function addChainsaw():void 
    {
        TweenLite.delayedCall(nChainsaw, addChainsaw);
        var newChainsaw = new mcChainsaw();
        //Add Child
        addChild(newChainsaw);
        //Push Move CLips into array
        aChainsawArray.push(newChainsaw);
        trace(aChainsawArray.length + "chainsaw");
    }
```

Now I want the `chainsaw` Movie clip in the array to be added to the stage every 2 seconds which is what the value of nChainsaw is. Ill kill it off when the nScore reaches a higher number. But as of right now when I test the Game like so It adds Multiple Movie clips  over and over again then freezes the game. I know it has to do with the ENTER_FRAME Listener But I don't know what else to do. SHould I just remove the TweenLite and add A Actual Timer and in the `diffucultyController();` just add timer.start??

If anyone has anyother Ideas I would really Appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Most likely: infinite loop issues. Hard to say without seeing the `ENTER_FRAME` listener.

Comment: the only thing inside the ENTER_FRAME Listener is the function diffucultyController();

Comment: It might just be something specific with Tweenlite though. Might have to use a timer instead even thought that slows down performance greatly

Comment: if you are really looking to call a certain function every certain number of seconds, then avoid both `ENTER_FRAME` as well as `TweenLite` and simply use `setInterval` attached to an `intervalID` or even better, a `Timer` object and control that. Once your certain condition reaches, you could get rid of the `setInterval` or the `Timer` object.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance , it's good to avoid enter frame and use timer events as @TahirAhmed said.